# Upgrade from PHP 7.0 to 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 not working

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I am sucessfully running 7.0 and would like to upgrade to 7.1.

So far I've done the following,

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo service apache2 start
```

Now, `php -v` gives me 7.1.1 but `phpinfo()` is saying 7.0.15

What am I missing, is there a config file I need to change somewhere?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

This might be also that you have installed your php7.1 but the php7.0 mod is still enabled.

In the cli if you run `php -v` you have the correct version 7.1 but in the `phpinfo()` you will see php7.0.
Disable php 7.0 with `sudo a2dismod php7.0` and you will have 7.1 working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this...

I've since done,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Seemed to do the trick.

I had to install some modules which were missing from the new version but other than that, all good.

Comment: Was phpfpm involved?  I smell a long-running php process that wasn't restarted after the upgrade.

Comment: @DylanMartin The problem was that Steve wrote "apt-get install php7.1" when that is not a package. Just installing php7.0 will install the newest version avaible

Comment: php7.1 is definitely a package, I installed it. See [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.1), or [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

Comment: phpfpm wasn't invloved as far as I know, not sure what was going on. All I know is it works now.

Comment: @Steve Oh, I thought about php7.0.12. Thanks for making it clear to me

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change path to your new php in your sites-available or apache config.
For nginx I have following:

```
...
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;                     
...
```